# how to get the value of a function from a button click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

i am new to javascript and am trying to go through tutorials to understand the concepts.

this is my function

```
function toCelsius(fahrenheit){

    (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);    
    document.getElementById("demoTemp").onclick.toString();

}
```

and i am trying to invoke it here:

```
<form>
<br>
Enter number: <input type="text" name="firstname">

<!-- <input type="text" name="lastname"> -->
<button type="button" onclick="toCelsius()"> new temp in Celsius </button>
</form>

<p id="demoTemp"></p>
```

i want the user to be able to enter a value and then hit the button that will tell them their new temperature from fahrenheit to celsius

Comment: Elegant way is first attach a 'click' event listener to required button. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener]
Then perform your logic as per one of the following answers.
It is important to understand event binding first. Also explore that event object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the result in the inner html.

```
function toCelsius(){
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
    var cel = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);    
    document.getElementById("demoTemp").innerHTML = cel;
}
```

Comment: He dont want pass fahrenheit, but get input value, use `document.getElementById("id").val` and add id `id` at your input

Answer (score 0):

You should make your function in this way :

```
  function toCelsius(){    var fahrenheit = document.getElementById('firstname').value; var cel=     (5/9) * (fahrenheit -32);        document.getElementById("demoTemp").innerHTML = cel;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass anything in the function. Try this JS :-

```
function toCelsius(){
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
    var cel = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);    
    document.getElementById("demoTemp").innerHTML = cel;
}
```